# Airbyte is failing replication after 5 or 6 tables

Tags: postgresql, debezium, airbyte

I am working on implementing the Airbyte in my organization but we have a problem that I can not manage to solve. We have a replication from Postgres 11 to Postgres 11 databases using CDC and it works fine for the first 5 or 6 tables but after I added another one to the replication it start failing. The tricky part is that it replicates the rows but throws failure anyway. Here you can. find the error messages:

[image]